# Stack Alignment for an indeterminate number of children

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building an app in flutter and part of what I am doing is fetching a list of actions from a server then building buttons for each action. I am trying to display the buttons in a circle and generate a list of raised button widgets. I am then trying to use a Stack to lay out this list in a circle, but cannot figure out how to use positioning to position objects in a circle when I do not know how many objects I will have (I know it will be in a range of about 3-15).

Here is the build method for my stack. Assume all methods and lists and variables are defined correctly and work. I am just concerned about the alignment

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> actions = [];
    for(var action in widget.actionsList){
      actions.add(RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => _handleAction(action[0]),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        child: Text(action[1] + ': ' + action[2]),
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: actions,
          alignment: //HELP,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you have any ideas about how to do the alignment or another way to go about this to make a circle of buttons please let me know. I really want to make a circle, but am not wedded to it impossible (which I doubt) or super convoluted.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to take widgets as a list and show a limited number of widgets in stack with the help of Positioning widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

**TL;DR;**

```
  final actionsList = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
          children: layedOutButtons(
            centerOfCircle:
                Offset(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) / 2,
            circleRadius: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Offset getCoordinateFromAngle({double radius, double angle}) => Offset(
        radius * sin(angle),
        radius * cos(angle),
      );

  List<Widget> layedOutButtons({
    Offset centerOfCircle,
    double circleRadius,
  }) {
    var buttonRadius = 25.0;
    var dispatchAngle = pi * 2 / actionsList.length;

    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    var i = 0;

    for (var action in actionsList) {
      var position = getCoordinateFromAngle(
        radius: circleRadius,
        angle: dispatchAngle * i++,
      );
      widgets.add(
        Positioned(
          top: centerOfCircle.dy - position.dy - buttonRadius,
          left: centerOfCircle.dx + position.dx - buttonRadius,
          width: buttonRadius * 2,
          height: buttonRadius * 2,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Text(action),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return widgets;
  }
```

**Explanation**

If you want to dispatch a number of widgets on a circle, you have to:

1. define `centerOfCircle`, the position of the center of that circle. To do so, I use the `LayoutBuilder` widget to get the constraints of the layout and determine the center of the `Stack` => (width / 2, height / 2).
2. define `circleRadius`, the radius of that circle (in my example: 100)

Give those data to `layedOutButtons` that will dispatch widgets on the circle with the `Positioned` widget.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
          children: layedOutButtons(
            centerOfCircle: Offset(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) / 2,
            circleRadius: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> layedOutButtons({
    Offset centerOfCircle,
    double circleRadius,
  }) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];

    for (var action in actionsList) {
      widgets.add(
        Positioned(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Text(action),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return widgets;
  }
```

Now, you need to define how you will dispatch the widgets on the circle, based on their number. e.g, it there's 2 widgets, dispatch them at 180° from each other (meaning one on the top of the circle, one on the bottom. If there's 4, dispatch at 90° from each other, etc. Note that it is expressed in radians (not in degrees).

```
var dispatchAngle = pi * 2 / actionsList.length;
```

Then you have to define the coordinates (x, y) of a point on a circle based on an angle (look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260096/find-the-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-circle)).

```
Offset getCoordinateFromAngle({double radius, double angle}) => Offset(
      radius * sin(angle),
      radius * cos(angle), 
    );
```

Use that to fill the `top` and `left` attributes of the `Positioned` widget.

```
  List<Widget> layedOutButtons({
    Offset centerOfCircle,
    double circleRadius,
  }) {
    var dispatchAngle = pi * 2 / actionsList.length;

    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    var i = 0;

    for (var action in actionsList) {
      var position = getCoordinateFromAngle(
        radius: circleRadius,
        angle: dispatchAngle * i++, //increment angle for each widget
      );
      widgets.add(
        Positioned(
          top: centerOfCircle.dy - position.dy, //something's wrong here
          left: centerOfCircle.dx + position.dx, //something's wrong here
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Text(action),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return widgets;
  }
```

Now everything is almost ready except that there's a misalignement. It's due to the fact that the widgets are positioned based on their top left corners. We want to refine the positioning so it match the center of our widgets.

```
var buttonRadius = 25.0;

Positioned(
  top: centerOfCircle.dy - position.dy - buttonRadius,
  left: centerOfCircle.dx + position.dx - buttonRadius,
  width: buttonRadius * 2,
  height: buttonRadius * 2,
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Text(action),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```